# How can I make this demo drawing game update drawing the circles faster with Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make my drawing game draw a circle where I drag my mouse, but the circles won't update often enough to create a smooth line. How can I fix this?

```
import pygame
from random import randint
width=800
height=600
pygame.init() #As necessary as import, initalizes pygame
global gameDisplay 
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))#Makes window
pygame.display.set_caption('Demo')#Titles window
clock = pygame.time.Clock()#Keeps time for pygame


gameDisplay.fill((0,0,255))

class Draw:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = (255, 0, 0)

    def update(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, self.color, (self.x, self.y), (5))


end = False
down = False
Line = Draw()
while not end:
    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    #drawShape()
    #pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, (0,255,0), (10, 10, 4, 4))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            down = True

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            down = False

        if down:
            Line.update(x, y)

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            end = True
    lastx, lasty = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

This is what my problem looks like

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the circle updating causes the problem? If you don't draw anything and only check the actual cursor position, do you get an event for every single pixel that the mouse moves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to draw a line from the previous mouse position to the current mouse position. Additionally draw a dot at the start and the end of the line. That causes a round beginning and end.
Track the previous position of the mouse (`lastx`, `lasty`) and draw the line in the main application loop rather than the event loop:

e.g.:

[image]

```py
import pygame

width, height = 800, 600
pygame.init() #As necessary as import, initalizes pygame
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height)) #Makes window
pygame.display.set_caption('Demo') #Titles window
clock = pygame.time.Clock() #Keeps time for pygame
gameDisplay.fill((0,0,255))

class Draw:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = (255, 0, 0)

    def update(self, from_x, from_y, to_x, to_y):
        pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, self.color, (from_x, from_y), 5)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, self.color, (from_x, from_y), (to_x, to_y), 10)
        pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, self.color, (to_x, to_y), 5)

end = False
down = False
line = Draw()
while not end:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            lastx, lasty = event.pos
            down = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            down = False
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            end = True

    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 
    if down:
        line.update(lastx, lasty, x, y)
    lastx, lasty = x, y

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```